# How to array_wrap an hash of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

```
inv = {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>{"name"=>"a"}}}} is my object
```

I want

```
inv = {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>[{"name"=>"a"}]}}}
```

I tried

```
inv["C"]["CPS"].inject({}) do |result, (k, v)|
  k = Array.wrap(v)
end

=>  [{"name"=>"a"}]
```

but still `inv={"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>{"name"=>"a"}}}}`

tries `map` also

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `tap`

```
inv["C"]["CPS"].tap do |h|
  h["CP"] = [h["CP"]] #or Array.wrap(h["CP"]) in rails
end
inv
#=> {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>[{"name"=>"a"}]}}}
```

`tap` will yield the current object so you can modify it in place.

**Update**

Inspired by @CarySwoveland's broader application you could use something like this as well.

```
class HashWrapper
  attr_reader :original_hash
  attr_accessor :target_keys

  def initialize(h,*target_keys)
    @original_hash = h 
    @target_keys = target_keys
  end

  def wrapped_hash
    @wrapped_hash ||= {}
  end

  def wrap_me
    original_hash.each do |k,v|
      value = v.is_a?(Hash) ? HashWrapper.new(v,*target_keys).wrap_me : v
      wrapped_hash[k] = wrap(k,value)
    end
    wrapped_hash
  end
private
  def wrap(k,v)
    target_keys.include?(k) ? [v] : v
  end
end
```

Then implementation is as follows

```
wrapper = HashWrapper.new(inv,"CP")
wrapper.wrap_me
#=> {"C"=>
      {"CPS"=>
        {"CP"=>
           [
            {"name"=>"a"}
           ]
        }
      }
    } 
new_wrapper = HashWrapper.new(inv,"CP","CPS")
new_wrapper.wrap_me
#=> {"C"=>
      {"CPS"=>
         [
           {"CP"=>
             [
              {"name"=>"a"}
             ]
           }
         ]
      }
    }
```

This assumes unique keys all the way through the hierarchy otherwise nested keys of the same name will be wrapped in the same fashion from the bottom up.
e.g.

```
inv = {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>{"name"=>"a"}},"CP" => "higher level"}}
HashWrapper.new(inv,"CP").wrap_me
#=> {"C"=>
      {"CPS"=>
        {"CP"=>
           [
             {"name"=>"a"}
           ]
      }, 
      "CP"=>
        [
         "higher level" 
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
hash = {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>{"name"=>"a"}}}}
val = hash["C"]["CPS"]["CP"]
val_as_arr = [val] # can optionally call flatten here
hash["C"]["CPS"]["CP"] = val_as_arr
puts hash
# => {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=> [{"name" => "a"}] }}}
```

basically

1. get the value
2. convert to array
3. set the value

There is no iteration required here i.e. `map` or `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use recursion, in the form of a compact and easily readable method that has broader application than solutions that only work with your specific hash.

```
def wrap_it(h)
  h.each { |k,v| h[k] = v.is_a?(Hash) ? wrap_it(v) : [v] }
  h
end

h = { "C"=>{ "CPS"=>{ "CP"=>{ "name"=>"a" } } } }
wrap_it(h)
  #=> {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>{"name"=>["a"]}}}}

h = { "C"=>{ "CPS"=>{ "CP"=>{ "CPPS"=> { "name"=>"cat" } } } } }
wrap_it(h)
  #=> {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>{"CPPS"=>{"name"=>["cat"]}}}}}

h = { "C"=>{ "CPS"=>{ "CP"=>{ "CPPS"=> { "name"=>"cat" } },
                      "DP"=>{ "CPPPS"=>"dog" } } } }
wrap_it(h)
  #=> {"C"=>{"CPS"=>{"CP"=>{"CPPS"=>{"name"=>["cat"]}}, "DP"=>{"CPPPS"=>["dog"]}}}}
```